# kendo combobox different css for alternative items

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-combobox

I am having an mvc kendo CombBox declared as

```
var comboBox = Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
         .Name("Combo")
         .Placeholder("Select a val...")
         .DataTextField("Description")
         .DataValueField("Description")
         .AutoBind(false)
         .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
         .DataSource(source => source
             .Read(read => read.Action("XYZ", "ABC").Data("callList"))
             .ServerFiltering(true)
             )
         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:400px" });
```

Is there any way to have different css for alternative items.

I couldnt find any thing in the kendo documentation. I also tried with JQuery but had failed. Can anyone tell if there is solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your browser support (IE9 or higher), you can do this with plain old CSS.

```
#Combo .k-item:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this works since the list of options is not a child of `#Combo`. The idea is fine but the way for limiting it to a single element doesn't work.

Comment: I had tried your answer but it didnt work. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I think if the dropdown is created from existing elements then it works, otherwise Kendo seems to move them off to its own dropdown panel. There is probably a way to get that element through JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#States").kendoComboBox();
        var cmb = $("#States").data("kendoComboBox");

        cmb.ul.find("li:odd").css("background-color", "#C0C0C0");
        cmb.ul.find("li:odd").css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    });
```

check this kendo dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/ePIQu
I am using Kendo Web not MVC but the result will be same as long as this script runs after the grid is populated.